# How to import csv date format in BigQuery uisng google appscript

Tags: python, csv, date, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have my data stored in CSV with format 2017-08-07 for my date column defined as string field in BQ. When I try to import all my data in BigQuery, all the date data has been converted to Mon Aug 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT). I want to import all the date ranges in the 2017-08-07 format but it is being converted with the above format.  Below is my script in CSV to upload data in BQ:

```
function test() {

  var projectId = 'test1';
  var datasetId = 'YoutubeNG';
     var yestDate = new Date();
      yestDate.setDate(yestDate.getDate()-2);
   var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(yestDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var tableId = 'Youtube_Keystats_NG';
  var fileId = '1y4xTZ4g1c08D8NOU0O-SWsi-5uyi9ukOuKLD5yz03cY';

  // Define our load job.
  var jobSpec = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        allowJaggedRows: true,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        schema: {
          fields: [{name:'Date', type: 'STRING',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Account_ID', type: 'INTEGER',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Account', type: 'STRING',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Campaign_ID', type: 'INTEGER',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Campaign_name', type: 'STRING',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Impressions', type: 'INTEGER',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Clicks', type: 'INTEGER',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Cost', type: 'FLOAT',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Conversions', type: 'FLOAT',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Value_per_conversion', type: 'FLOAT',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Total_conversion_value', type: 'FLOAT',mode:'NULLABLE'},
                   {name:'Average_position', type: 'FLOAT',mode:'NULLABLE'},

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var filename = spreadsheet.getName();

  var MAX_ROWS = 50000;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tableId); 
  //var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; //.getSheetByName("Expenses")
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var csvdata = "";
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length && row < MAX_ROWS + 1; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      var cell = data[row][col].toString();
      if (cell.indexOf(",") != -1) {
        csvdata += "\"" + cell + "\"";
      } else {
        csvdata += cell;
      }

      if (col < data[row].length - 1) {
        csvdata += ",";
      }
    }
    csvdata += "\r\n";
  }
  var data = Utilities.newBlob(csvdata, "application/octet-stream");

  // Execute the job.
  BigQuery.Jobs.insert(jobSpec, projectId, data);
}
```

Comment: You mean the date in your DB is a date? it exactly what you want. Now you can ask the DB the format you want. ( dd/mm/yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd ....). don't think what you see is what on the DB.

Comment: I mean the date format in my csv is 2017-08-07 but when uploading to Bigquery using the above codes it is being converted to Mon Aug 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT). I want to display the date date in BigQuery as 2017-08-07 NOT Mon Aug 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the line `var cell = data[row][col].toString();` will convert the content of a cell to a string. After importing the date has been stored as a dateTime type and will be converted to a string using the standard formatting, hence the undesired output.
You have to explicitly convert your dateTime column with the format you want.
To better understand whats going on internally, I propose you look at the content of your cells with a debugger.

Comment: The date has been set up as a STRING data type. Problem is that in my csv, i have the date data as 2017-08-07 but when uploading it in the BQ it shows as Mon Aug 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT). Don't know why it is being converted.